# Control two different DPDT circuits with one DPDT switch

Tags: usb, hdmi, dpdt

I have a HDMI switch (pictured below) and a USB 2.0 Switch both have dual inputs and a single output, with no external power input. Both from what I can see are switched via DPDT switch. What I want to achieve is have them both controlled by a single DPDT switch instead of their own switches, as I plan to put them together in a 3D printed case to make a crude KVM switch.

I’m not sure if I can just wire them up to the same switch or if I need anything additional to isolate the two circuits as I guess they will run on different voltages etc?

Any help is appreciated.

[image: Top view of HDMI switch]

[image: Bottom view of HDMI switch]

Comment: have you looked up the datasheets of the two switching ICs and see whether they take similar control input? if so, that's basically your solution.

Comment: You need to provide the manufacturer's datasheets for the two modules before anyone can possibly help you. Edit the question to add links to the datasheets, and not to vendor pages on ebay or aliexpress.

Comment: Does the USB switch seems alike the HDMI switch pictured? If a single DPDT can switch HDMI, it's possible that DPDT is just controling two logical inputs of the switcher IC, each logic pin enables one input, and if both switches are similar, **maybe** what you want can be done. You could start measuring voltages in the DPDT switches pins.

Comment: Where would I go about getting Datasheets for these? They are just switches I bought off Amazon and opened up to look inside. The USB switch is very similar to the HDMI one pictured here. I will try and get an image of that today also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a 4PDT switch, replacing the 2 DPDT switches. Or you can make your 3d case press both switches at the same time (a bar or fitting over two dpdt switches, like a large cap).

Or you can figure out the IC on the board to see if the switch is just toggling the ICs enable pin. You shouldn't need to isolate them, if you share the ground between the two. If you do need isolation then you can use optocouplers. This requires some electronic knowledge but start with pulling datasheets.